# Determine if List View is either builtin or custom

Tags: list-view

What is the safest way to determine if a list view is either builtin (came with Sharepoint by default) or custom (created by a user) ?

Answer (score 1):

Most lists only come with an All Items view, but it depends on what type of list it is.  You can open the site in SharePoint Designer and look at the list forms.  The AllItems.aspx (or whatever the default forms are for that list type) will have a date/time stamp from when the list was created.  Any other aspx pages will be either forms for the list (DispForm, NewForm, EditForm) or additional forms. The date/time stamps on those pages ought to tell you when they were created.  If the date/time doesn't match the AllItems.aspx page, then it's highly likely that the views were created by a user.

Answer (score 0):

You could look in the 12/Template/Features directories for the List Template feature matching the list in question and compare it to the schema.xml's declared views. I'm not sure if any OOTB views are created programmatically by built-in features, so this is probably not the 'safest' way.

I didn't see a way to determine this via the UI or SharePoint Manager 2007.